# How to access dynmaically added Textbox values ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview placed on a ASP.Net WebSite, and added a column dynamically like this:

```
protected void gvGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (DataControlRowType.DataRow == e.Row.RowType && e.Row.RowState != DataControlRowState.Edit &&
        (e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Normal || e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Alternate))
    {
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        tb.ID = "tb";
        tb.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
        int i = e.Row.Cells.Count;
        i = i - 1;
        e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(tb);
    }
}
```

The gridview is populated, and at the end of every row the TextBox is added. When I look at the HTML Code that is delived to the Browser, I can see that the ID of every Textbox is "gv_Items_tb_X" with X being the current row index.
Now I would like to access the content that the user types in the tb on a button click. I tried following code, but it I get an exception becuase the textbox is null.

```
protected void btn_UpdateCount_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OI_Data_Service.OI_Data_ServiceClient sc = new OI_Data_Service.OI_Data_ServiceClient();
    foreach (GridViewRow row in gv_Items.Rows)
    {
        if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            TextBox tb_value = (TextBox)gv_Items.Rows[row.RowIndex].Cells[5].FindControl("gv_Items_tb_" + row.RowIndex);
            sc.UpdateItemOnOpening("1", row.Cells[0].Text, tb_value.Text);
        }
    }
    Response.Redirect("~/okay.aspx");
}
```

Can anyone tell my what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you are going down deep enough, try creating a Quick Watch on the line of code in question and seeing what gv_items.Controls has in it. I would think that you need the individual Row and Cell as that is where you are adding the control

Comment: Thanks Daniel for the quick reply. What do you mean with creating a "Quick Watch"? A Breakpoint?

Comment: IDs are changed when rendered. Try adding the attribute of the textboxes to  `ClientIDMode` set to `static`

Comment: Yes breakpoint then right click when it hits breakpoint in VS and click Quick Watch, you can then choose individual variables to see their values and drill down etc

Comment: I'd add an image, but unfortunately  my reputation isn't good enough yet ;) It has "null" as value